# How to transform this "7.33E+11" to a standard number (i.e. UPC code)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, formatting

I have a difficulty with transforming this 7.33E+11
in Excel. I had many rows with 6,22357E+11 which I can easily transform to number and it is all fine, but what happens with the one with the "." When I replace the dot with coma it just shows 9 zeros after 33, which is not ok. I have this information in .tsv files where in one column are located UPC codes,but some are with "," others with ".", I have combined all .tsv and saved the file as a standard Excel workbook, but the problem still occurs....My Excel reads probably "." as text.

Thanks,
Ivan

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the locales (to english eg.) or filter the source file before the import. It is possible to use find/replace also inside the Excel sheet. Ofcourse, if you change the dot (".") to comma (",") in the .csv (may be the similar as .tsv) file `csv = comma separated values` you get two values: `7` and `33E+11` from the original `7.33E+11`. Hence you need to change first all commas to eg. semicollon ";" and than change the dots to commas. The import filter have to ask you for the pending separator and text enclosure prior the import starts.